# Customer Address Attributes with Magento Generator

Tags: magento2.4

I did a Module with the generator of https://mage2gen.com/

It is about 4 new fields in Customer Address (all required)

It show in form at checkout, admin, etc. All perfect.

But!

If I realize a payment it doesn't save the data at DB or in Sales -> Orders. All fields are empty

I'm pretty new in Magento and I don't know how to make it works.

If can guide me, I apreciate.

Thanks

Comment: Please share the code at6 here what you have  tried